# Trying to convert a text to a java string array

Tags: java, android, string, sorting

I'm trying to have an `EditText` that will check every word written while ignoring all special characters, and and add it to a String array. My idea was to make every new word clickable and use it to connect to an API.

I've tried a few things a found on the internet but never really worked.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     String string = editText_Main.getText().toString();
     String[] arr = string.split(" ");

     for ( String ss : arr) {
          System.out.println("Adding: " + ss + " to words array");
          words.add(ss);
     }
     System.out.println("Words array -> "+words);
}
```

So the idea was just to use the words array for creating all of the links and somehow using it to also link them to the `EditText`, but maybe this is a completely wrong approach and someone can lead me on a better path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
String string = editText_Main.getText().toString();
```

you should use

```
String string = s.getText().toString();
```